How to stop current leaks on PC casing?
I'm experiencing an electrical current leak on my PC casing(metal). When I touch the metal parts of the case, I feel a mild shock or tingle. I'm concerned about potential safety hazards and damage to my components.
What steps should I take to identify and stop the current leak on my PC casing?
Here are some additional details:

The PC is plugged into a standard power outlet.(3 pin plug which connected to earth)
I've noticed the issue persists regardless of which outlet I use.
The power supply unit (PSU) is relatively new, but I'm not sure if it
might be the culprit.
i have no idea if the metal casing is connected to earth from inside.

Any advice on how to safely diagnose and fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Try earthing the case.

Y-capacitor leakage/lack of grounding. See more here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321164/leakage-current-in-in-line-mains-filters

Basic stuff: does your PC have a 3-prong earthed inlet? Does the inlet earth connect to case? Does it have a mains cord which has plugs with earth connection and is there an earth wire between plugs? Does your wall receptacle have an earth prong and does an earth wire connect to it?

@Justme 1.yes hv 3 pin socket. 2.idk  3. dont know 4. yes

@ those voting to close for "Needs details or clarity" : can you please explain what is unclear or what details are missing? For me, the question is clear, and contains all the details I would expect a non technical person to provide. Feel free to ask for additional details if needed. In fact, asking for those traditional details is in part what OP is expecting as answers (ie what to look for to identify the cause)

@Sandro The problem is, that this behaviour is normal for notebooks, laptops and some sort of PC with external PSU (Y-capacitor effect), but not normal (dangerous) for a typical desktop or tower PC with internal PSU. It is not fully clear, what we have here. And there is the even more dangerous possibility, that PE connection is lost on multiple power outlets and the PC is not the problem.

@Jens : I was assuming a tower PC (because of metal casing), but it's not certain. But if I were the OP, I think I would never have guessed it's unclear if not asked for clarification in a comment. And globally, I would say your comment could be an answer (maybe not the most complete one, but clearly useful)

@Andyaka Will it stop the leak ?

First thing would be to get a known good IEC power cable and swap it in; that's a very common place for OEMs to skimp. If the problem persists, then buy one of those cheap outlet wiring testers from a hardware store for $10 or so. If the test shows that your outlet is good, then replace the PSU.  If the test shows that your outlet is not grounded, then stop using it (the outlet) and call an electrician.

Given your other recent question, I'm worried about your mains wiring.  I reckon you need to test the socket
